# Add JAudiotagger Library to Java on Windows 7

Tags: java, groovy

I am a (very) amateur programmer. I am using Groovy to edit MP3 file tags.  Previously (about two years ago), I added the `JAudiotagger` class library to my Java installation using the detailed instructions given in the `JAudiotagger` readme file, and then called the required classes from my Groovy script. However, there is no readme file (that I can find) in the latest version of `JAudiotagger`, and I have so far failed to work out what to do.

Please can someone give me simple instructions on how to add `JAudiotagger` to Java, e.g. what files do I need to download, from where and what do I do with them.

I am running Windows 7.

All help gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to simply download the jar of jAutioTagger and put it in your classpath, so when the program launch, the classes in the jar should be accessible: [java classpath](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/background/13files_and_directories/20classpath.html)

Now if you want a more generic way of handling dependencies altogether, i suggest you start reading about [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) (which a build tool with dependecny managment).

You can also use [gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) which looks more for groovy but I do not know about it.

As for starting a new project with maven it requires some steps. Here is a lightweight tutorial:

1. Create a maven project
2. Add the desired dependencies in your pom.xml
3. Build the project with libraries embedded
4. Run the program

#### Create a maven project

Type in the following command in your command line:

> mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=5-SNAPSHOT

It will ask you some questions like the group id and the artifact id as well as the project name.

#### Add the desired dependencies in your pom.xml

The pom.xml is where you configure your project, like build things and dependencies, to have audiotagger as a dependency add the following:

> ```
>   <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.jaudiotagger</groupId>
>       <artifactId>jaudiotagger</artifactId>
>       <version>2.0.1</version>
>   </dependency>
> ```

This will add jaudiotagger to the dependencies of your project, you can add groovy as well. You'll also need dependencies too groovy and the [groovy compiler](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy-Eclipse+compiler+plugin+for+Maven).

*Hint*: I use [sonatype](https://repository.sonatype.org/index.html) to find dependencies

#### Build the project with libraries embedded

Now to build your project with maven. Just type the following command:

> mvn clean install

but this will not add the dependencies to your jar, so you need to embedd them by adding a plugin to your pom.xml configuration:

> ```
>    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
>    <configuration>
>        <archive>
>            <manifest>
>                <mainClass>be.phury.audiotagger.Audiotagger</mainClass>
>            </manifest>
>        </archive>
>        <descriptorRefs>
>            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
>        </descriptorRefs>
>    </configuration>
> ```

You can now generate a jar with dependencies by typing in the command line:

> mvn clean install assembly:single

#### Run the program

Just run the jar

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much!  I've spent several days flailing around, downloading and umpacking jars, installing Maven and I don't know what else.  It took me about one minute to follow your instructions and successfully access JAudiotagger from Groovy.

I don't think I need Maven at the moment, and I don't really understand what it does, but I might explore the second part of your answer in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to go through Maven/Gradle, you could also use the @Grapes annotation:

```
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='org.jaudiotagger', module='jaudiotagger', version='2.0.1')
)
```

in top of your Groovy script, that would download your dependencies whereever you start your script. I found the dependency http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jaudiotagger/jaudiotagger/2.0.1 - they even make the full @Grapes notation for you.